# Throw exception on invalid ZIP code or validate with method?

Tags: c#, validation, exception

I have an application that takes a ZIP code from the user which may or may not be valid for the selected state. I consider the case of an invalid ZIP code to be a rare issue that would really only result from a typo.

The relevant SQL tables are `Quote` and `Address`. Saving a quote is done in one database call, with all parameters for both tables being supplied to a stored procedure.

Currently in the case of an invalid ZIP code an exception is raised in the stored procedure, caught in C# at the data layer, and a custom `InvalidZipCodeException` is thrown. The custom exception is then caught at the UI layer and the user is notified of the error. I originally designed it this way to avoid an extra database call to check the validity of the ZIP code every time a quote is saved.

I've recently read some materials on data validation and realized I'm using exceptions to control logic flow here, which is generally frowned upon. It seems silly to me to make a separate database call just to validate the ZIP code when the overwhelming majority of cases involve valid data. I'd like some more educated opinions on whether my design is poor in this specific case.

Comment: I think this question belongs to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am sure you have a good reason but for my sake, why do you need to talk to the database to validate a zip code? Could you not use a pattern for this?

Comment: What do you do in the case of duplicate usernames, for example? I imagine the process will be similar here.

Comment: @Petrichor this is actually an internal WinForms insurance app, no usernames. This is really the only such case in this app. Do you mean using a regular expression? If so, not every string of 5 digits is a valid ZIP code.

Comment: Either's OK; though it's best to avoid using exceptions for validation you have to weigh that against your other concerns.  You could do the validation in the background (e.g via AJAX call if web based) as the user fills out the rest of the form; that way the user knows about the issue before they've even submitted the form / it doesn't take any time to correct.  However you want a consistent approach throughout your app for all validation (if possible), and you don't want to spend lots of time perfecting how validation's at the cost of other priorities.

Comment: @JohnLBevan thanks for the insight, I was thinking it would be a sort of "if it makes sense in a specific case it's OK" but wanted to get some other opinions.

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly please move it for me if so, I'm not sure I have the privilege of moving it. In any case, I don't know how.

Comment: You could return a status message instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: Since zip codes can cross state boundaries, I would think you have no choice but to do it with either a database lookup or a web service, especially you're considering ZIP + 4.  For those that said "just do a pattern", "48104" is a valid zip code, but not for New York.

Answer (score 0):

As JohnLBevan suggests in the comments, it's really not worth reworking it if (1) it's already working OK and (2) it's consistent with how the rest of the application validates. While it is currently thought to be bad practice to control logic flow with exceptions, like anything else it's a judgement call.

You mentioned that every 5 digit number is not a valid zip code... I imagine you have a table that stores a   map to validate. Just store that as a dictionary and validate against it client-side, if you end up changing the validation. For me, I would say, "If it ain't broke, don't fix it" in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I actually don't have a map table, my thinking is that there are some 43,000 ZIP codes in the US so it would be inefficient to store them all in memory.